# "Умозрительно" как синоним "мысленно" - возможно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, синонимы

> Мы должны повторить скульптуру своим телом, как минимум **умозрительно
>   принять подобное положение** и прислушаться. Но прежде следует
>   рассмотреть фигуру Моисея со всех возможных сторон и с наибольшей
>   подробностью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, это слово *не подходит* к авторскому контексту. Обычно оно употребляется по отношению к *рассуждениям и выводам*, опирающимся на *предполагаемые* факты или обстоятельства (напр. когда реальные недоступны). Это именно о деятельности **ума**, а не просто воображения. Здесь правильнее "мысленно".

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что эта фраза корректна. Здесь ***умозрительно*** — это действительно ***мысленно***, эти слова часто употребляются как синонимы.

УМОЗРИТЕЛЬНЫЙ,  Книжн.  **Основанный на умозрении;** абстрактный, отвлечённый.

Умозре́ние (лат. speculatio) — 1) деятельность мышления, вращающаяся в сфере предметов или событий, не данных на опыте, но лишь предполагаемых; 2) **мышление, содержание которого — только мыслимое** или сверхчувственное.

Синонимы: [https://sinonim.org/s/мысленно](https://sinonim.org/s/%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пару цитат в качестве расширенного комментария к другим ответам.

> И зритель в зале **умозрительно** фиксирует эту остановку, он умозрительно
>   принимает необходимость клумбы, ибо иного он сделать не может. ("Театр",
>   1976)
>
> Средневековый художник представлял себе мир **умозрительно**: фигуры,
>   предметы, пейзаж ... ("Художественные средства композиции в
>   изобразительном искусстве")
>
> Иными словами: искусство ребенка **умозрительно**, искусство взрослого —
>   отображательно (Эфрос). (Из дневников М.М. Пришвина)